# Super context in subclass call (javascript)

Tags: javascript, class

I have a class map as shown below:

```
class A {
  do(input) { return input + ' A'; }
}
class B extends A {
  do(input) { return input + ' B'; }
  run() { return `This call: ${this.do()}, super call: ${super.do()}`; }
}
class C extends B {
  do(input) { return input + ' C'; }
}
let inst = new C();
console.log(inst.run());
```

I expect one of two situations:

- In this call `this.do` will be class C `do` and `super.do` will be class B `do` (as we call `run` from C and his `super` is B)
- In this call `this.do` will be class B `do` and `super.do` will be class A `do` (as we declare `run` in B and his `super` is A)

But i find out that `this` and `super` have different contexts: `this` is class C and `super` is class A. 
My real task is running only class B `do` and i can't find the way to do it.